# Best container for coordinates

Tags: c++, xlib

I'm currently trying to pick up coordinates from a txt file in use of xlib and I've been wondering what's the best container to use for such an endeavor? I was thinking multidimensional arrays since my program is going to work with triangles and a shortest path algorithm I also wanted to ask how best to fill said container using the scan function too, the plan is to use use nested loops in order to fill it up.

EDIT: The txt file that I'm planning on using is a list of triangle coordinates to draw using the xlib function, Then by placing points on the interface, to find the shortest path from a user-defined spot to another, with the triangles serving as obstacles.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int A,B;
    int Trig[A][B];
    FILE * pFile;
    // First need to scan the file. Need to check if there's a file to look into first.
    std::string pFilename = argv[1];
    if (pFilename == ""){
        cout << "Needs a Filename";
    }
    pFile = fopen(atoi(pFilename),"r");
    // scanf(pFile,"%1s (%d,%d) (%d,%d) (%d,%d)",);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int Trig[A][B];` isn't allowed in C++. (Even worse, you haven't initialised `A` or `B`.)

Comment: You'll have to specify in more detail what you're going to do with the data; the correct data structure entirely depends on that. If you don't know, start with a `vector` of a simple `point` class.

Comment: I added more information on what I'd like to do with the coordinates of the triangle.

Answer (score 3):

If those are 2D coordinates, `std::pair` would be a great choice.

```
#include <utility>

int main()
{
  std::pair<int, int> intCoordinates(5, 3);

  std::cout << "x: " << intCoordinates.first;
  std::cout << "y: " << intCoordinates.second << "\n";

  // -- hocus pocus, array of pairs, use it as normal C array
  std::pair<int, int> arr[5];
}
```

Of course you can change the type of variables.
It can be `<double, double>` or even `<double, int>` if you want, that's completely up to you.

More informations: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/pair/

In **this or any other cases**, Point struct would do the job:

```
struct Point {
  int x, y;
  Point(int a, int b) { this->x = a; this->y = b; }
};

int main()
{
   Point p(2,3);

   // ...
}
```

We probably cannot give your more advices unless you bring us more informations about your code.

Comment: `pair` is generally a bad choice for anything that isn't two arbitrary pieces of data (see e.g. http://maintainablecode.logdown.com/posts/158531-stdpair-considered-harmful). Geometric points deserve a more expressive abstraction.

Comment: I added more info about the intent of the program.

Comment: That `Point` constructor needs an initializer-list.

Comment: I meant member-initializers, sorry.

Comment: While this sounds like a good idea, 1. I'd like to know the best way to gather all the points from a txt file detailing coordinates, since I'd need to use that source to make triangles.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently and found that post. I started using pair as suggested here but at the end it wasn't that easy to use and to maintain so I created my own Struct with some utilities operators.

.hpp

```cpp
struct Coordinates
{
    std::size_t x;
    std::size_t y;
    Coordinates(std::size_t x, std::size_t y);
    void add(std::size_t x, std::size_t y);

    Coordinates operator+=(const Coordinates &coordinate);
    Coordinates operator+(Coordinates coordinate);
};
```

.cpp

```cpp
Coordinates::Coordinates(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) : x(x), y(y)
{
}

void Coordinates::add(std::size_t xAdd, std::size_t yAdd)
{
    x += xAdd;
    y += yAdd;
}

Coordinates Coordinates::operator+=(const Coordinates &coordinate)
{
    add(coordinate.x, coordinate.y);
    return *this;
}

Coordinates Coordinates::operator+(Coordinates coordinate)
{
    return coordinate += *this;
}
```

Here is what you can do:

```cpp
Coordinates myPoint(4, 7);
myPoint += Coordinates(2, 3); // myPoint now contains x = 6 and y = 10
```

You can also access fields x and y by doing `yourPoint.x` or `yourPoint.y`.